# How to investigate Android SafetyNet API in Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-source, android-developer-api, safetynet, safetynet-api

I'm doing some research regarding [Android SafetyNet API](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/safetynet/attestation#request-attestation-step).

I'm searching for the source code implementing the APIs, but I can't find any from the following 2 channels

- [AOSP (Android Open Source Proejct)](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download/downloading#getting-the-files)

I downloaded the entire source tree but I found nothing related to SafetyNet. Is Android SDK part of AOSP? Or should I download an earlier version?

- The [Android Code Search](https://cs.android.com/)

The keyword `SafetyNetApi` matches nothing on this site.

Please help me find the source code implementing this API.

Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that things related to Google Play Services are not open-source and will be not be in the AOSP.